# Ituneslib API with itunes 9.0 compatibility issue

Tags: c#, api, com, itunes, compatibility

Ituneslib api stopped working with itunes 9.0. (exception in first interaction)
Is there an alternative API ? has anyone found a solution for it ?

It works perfectly in several computers with itunes 8.x, and just doesn't open (doesn't create COM object with itunes 9.x)

Any workarounds ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the iTunes 9.0 installation damaged the COM registration entries? Are you using x64 or x32? What version of Windows?

iTunes COM works fine with iTunes 9.0.2.25

Running:

```
Console.WriteLine("Version = {0}", (new iTunesLib.iTunesAppClass()).Version);
```

returns

```
Version = 9.0.2.25
```

for me. One way to check quickly is to try and instantiate thye iTunes COM object yourself without the interop libs. Say like this:

```
var itunes = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("iTunes.Application", true));
Console.WriteLine(itunes!=null?"All ok":"Did not work");
```